# how to get all edit text values in array list in customized listview using base adapter in android

Tags: android, android-listview

I am fetching all menunames from server database through url i append all menunames into editext customized listview using base adapter. now i am getting Edittext changed values into list array .now i want store edittext all values, whether he changes menunames or not.Eg:x,yz... menunames coming from database append to the editext now i am changed menuname y to b and z to c in editext.now i want [x,b.c...] vaules in arraylist but now i am getting b,c

```
          this is my code
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;


    if (convertView == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.editmainmenulist, null);
        holder.caption = (EditText) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.editmaimenu);
        holder.caption1=(ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.menuimage);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    //Fill EditText with the value you have in data source
    holder.caption.setText(itemnames[position]);//here only i append database menunames
    holder.caption.setId(position);
    holder.caption1.setImageBitmap(bmps[position]);

    //we need to update adapter once we finish with editing
    holder.caption.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus){
                final int position = v.getId();
                final EditText Caption = (EditText) v;
                itemnames[position] = Caption.getText().toString();

                arr.add(Caption.getText().toString());//here only i think problem..please see any body can tell what i have mistake has been done


            }
        }    
    });     

    return convertView;
}
      }

           class ViewHolder {
EditText caption;
ImageView caption1;
      }

    class ListItem {
String caption;
     }
```

i want all edittext values in whether the editext values change or not. for update purpous. 
i can get all menunames previous . i want update old menunames into new menunames

Comment: Got confused...whats your problem exactly?

Comment: Eg:in my editext contains x,y,z. i changed value y as b in editext ..now i want get x,b,z in arraylist.now ur understood my problem or not

Answer (score 1):

Add `TextChangedListener` to your `EditText` in `getView()`

**Code:**

```
holder.caption.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher()
{           
  @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub         
    }           
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after)
    {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     }
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s)
    {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String data =  holder.caption.getText().toString().trim();
    }
});
```

Now get the data from edittext when you want, onTextChanged, beforeTextChanged or afterTextChanged..

Comment: i use above method..i get after,before changed text.EG:xyz menunames comes from database append to edittext.now i cannot change menunames menase i want get x,y,z in array list. if i change edittext vlaue y to b menas i want get x,b.z in arraylist

Comment: Also you can use, @Override
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)
    {
     String data = s.toString()       
    }